# Why is this get_post_meta returning the wrong value?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Trying to show a display notice based on the previous page, using it's post ID.

The problem is that the post meta value is stored in Wordpress as 0 (zero), but my statement is returning it as being true, when it should be false.

```
$previous_page = url_to_postid(wp_get_referer());
$consultationFee = null;
if(get_post_meta($previous_page, '_wp_page_template', true) == 'template-procedure-minimal.php') {
    if(get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true) && get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true) === 0) {
        $consultationFee = false;
    } else {
        $consultationFee = true;
    }
}
var_dump($previous_page, get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true), $consultationFee);

C:\wamp64\www\bellavou\wp-content\themes\bellavou\template-request-consultation.php:11:int 3209
C:\wamp64\www\bellavou\wp-content\themes\bellavou\template-request-consultation.php:11:string '0' (length=1)
C:\wamp64\www\bellavou\wp-content\themes\bellavou\template-request-consultation.php:11:boolean true
```

I notice the var_dump of the value is being returned as a string. IS this right? This should be an integer. Anyway, even changing the IF statement to check against a string ie. `=== '0'` returns the wrong value still.

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code working right ( as written ).

1. First block:

   ```
   if(get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true)){

   }else{
     //will always work this code, because '0' converted to 0( false )
   }
   ```
2. Second block:

   ```
   if(get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true) === 0){

   }else{
     //will always work this code, because ( string )'0' not equeal to ( int )0
   }
   ```

   [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) will return string, if last parameter `$single` set as `true`. And will return empty string ( `''` ), if no value will found. So, we can't check it with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. `isset(get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true))` will always be true, and as you're expecting the return value be `( string )'0'` `empty(get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true))` will always be `true`.

Your `$consultationFee` will always be `true`, because:

```
if(get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true)/*returns false*/ && get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true) === 0/*returns false*/) {
    $consultationFee = false;
} else {
    //we will reach this block
    $consultationFee = true;
}
```

if you want to compare returned value of `get_post_meta` with `( string )'0'`, use this:

```
if(get_post_meta($previous_page, 'consultationFee', true) === '0'))
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure I agree with the points you made, but the last example you give seems to have worked (using string rather than integer)

Comment: the first point won't always be false, because the IF statement returns true if the post_meta value exists, regardless of it's content.

Comment: you mentioned, that the value returns '0' for that key, so it'll be '0', or ''. this always will be false